# Paypal Windows8 Checkout SDK is support for recurring payment?

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, paypal

i'm working with windows store application and i'm using PayPal Windows8 checkout SDK its working fine for normal payments but i need to make a recurring payment.Let me know PayPal Windows8 checkout SDK is supported for recurring payment?.

https://github.com/paypal/Windows8SDK

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like the PayPal Windows 8 SDK supports recurring payments right now.  If you go down into the API Reference sheet for C# you'll see there is no mention of a property or event allowing an item to reoccur.

Further, the SDK promotes the Checkout.BuyNow API.  BuyNow insinuates it's simply to be bought on the spot, which goes hand in hand with the entire SDK being called PayPal Checkout.

Version 1.0.0 went live yesterday and they seem to have kept semi regular updates in developing for it.  I can anticipate reoccuring payments being a heavily requested feature so I'd either check in on it from time to time or find another SDK/API that can help you.

Have fun!